# Как сделать сложный градиент для табов?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, svg

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот HTML

```
<div class="search_tabs">
    <div class="search_tab_pills">
        <label class="search_tab_pill" for="tab_1"><span>Аренда</span></label>
        <label class="search_tab_pill" for="tab_2"><span>Продажа</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="search_tab_content">
        <input type="radio" name="search_tabs_radios" class="search_tab_radio" id="tab_1" checked />
        <div class="search_tab_content_inner">
            <p>Контент таба Аренда</p>
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="search_tabs_radios" class="search_tab_radio" id="tab_2" />
        <div class="search_tab_content_inner">
            <p>Контент таба Продажа</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот CSS

```
.search_tab_pills {
    display: inline-flex;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
}

.search_tab_pill {
    display: inline-flex;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    min-height: 43px;
    min-width: 139px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(42, 56, 66, .6);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.search_tab_content {
    padding: 16px 24px 16px 24px;
    background: linear-gradient(0, #05ADE5 0%, #8ABE4B 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0, #05ADE5 0%, #8ABE4B 100%);
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    position: relative;
}

.search_tab_radio {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.search_tab_content .search_tab_radio + .search_tab_content_inner {
    display: none;
}

.search_tab_content .search_tab_radio:checked + .search_tab_content_inner {
    display: block;
}
```

Фоны кнопок "Аренда" и "Продажа" при переключении должны сливаться с фоном блока под ними. Как это сделать?

Вот как это работает сейчас [посмотреть](https://jsfiddle.net/dion_86/vtak4de0)

Answer (score 3):

Ну, как-то так можно... Только при переключении нужно активный класс навешивать, это скорее всего через js (пока закостылил, чтобы показать переключение в примере, но лучше полностью на js табы сделать).

```js
function setTab(tabLabel) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.search_tab_pill').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('search_tab_pill--active'))
  document.getElementById(tabLabel).classList.add('search_tab_pill--active')
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

.search_tabs_sect {
  max-width: 609px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.search_tab_pills {
  display: inline-flex;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}

.search_tabs {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #05ADE5 0%, #8ABE4B 100%);
  position: relative;
}

.search_tabs:before {
  content: '';
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 0%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 10px, #222 10px);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.search_tabs:after {
  content: '';
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 0%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 10px, #222 10px);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.search_tab_pills:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  background: #222;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 63px;
}

.search_tab_pill {
  display: inline-flex;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  min-height: 43px;
  min-width: 139px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*background: rgba(42, 56, 66, .6);*/
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #222;
  position: relative;
}

.search_tab_pill--active {
  background: transparent;
}

.search_tab_pill--active:before {
  content: '';
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 10px, #222 10px);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.search_tab_pill--active:after {
  content: '';
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 10px, #222 10px);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.search_tab_content {
  padding: 16px 24px 16px 24px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.search_tab_radio {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.search_tab_content .search_tab_radio+.search_tab_content_inner {
  display: none;
}

.search_tab_content .search_tab_radio:checked+.search_tab_content_inner {
  display: block;
}

.search_tab_content_inner p {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="search_tabs">
  <div class="search_tab_pills">
    <label class="search_tab_pill search_tab_pill--active" id="tab_1_label" for="tab_1" onclick="setTab('tab_1_label')"><span>Аренда</span></label>
    <label class="search_tab_pill" id="tab_2_label" for="tab_2" onclick="setTab('tab_2_label')"><span>Продажа</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="search_tab_content">
    <input type="radio" name="search_tabs_radios" class="search_tab_radio" id="tab_1" checked />
    <div class="search_tab_content_inner">
      <p>Контент таба Арен</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="search_tabs_radios" class="search_tab_radio" id="tab_2" />
    <div class="search_tab_content_inner">
      <p>Контент таба Продажа</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: С фоном не получилось((( У меня нет однотонного фона под табами. Табы с градиентом расположены по середине картинки главного экрана.

Comment: Ну а у Вас на скрине однотипный) С цветным, конечно не пойдёт. Тогда только подбирать градиент тайтла под позицию градиента в контенте, что оооочень сложно с учетом поддержки нескольких браузеров. Точно стоит игра свеч? Может лучше сделать проще? Пользователю не особо принципиально будет, даже не заметит скорее всего

Comment: Думаю для Аренды отдельный фон всех табов, а для Продажи тоже отдельный фон табов. То есть при переключении табов будут переключаться и фоны. Будем надеяться что заказчик захочет только Аренду и Продажу предлагать. А при ресайзе border-radius думаю не сильно будет Искажаться.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нужно или после вставлять кусок, который перекрывает оставшийся фон, или каждому тайтлу навешивать градиент - в этом случае градиенты наложатся на ширину тайтла узко, и придется прям подбирать на каждую вкладку градиент, и чуть что (адаптив сожмет, или нужно будет добавить вкладку), то автоматически появляется куча головной боли